# How to query time data from database with format HH:MM:SS from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with the following structure:

```
DateId  TimeId        ProfilerId    SensorId    SensorValue
------------------------------------------------------------
651     01:16:58.000    0              9           0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              10          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              11          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              12          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              13          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              14          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              15          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              16          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              17          0.00
651     01:16:58.000    0              18          0.00
651     01:16:59.000    0              0          -16965.60
651     01:16:59.000    0              1           164.80
651     01:16:59.000    0              2          -343.20
```

I am developing a front-end app that have a drop-down menu. To do that  I need to select the following:

- The first one minute
- The first one hour
- 7 days
- 1 month
- All

Currently if I do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Fact.Readings 
WHERE [TimeId] >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

I got an error

> The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator

How to query this type of time format (it is time(3) according to SQL table property)

Thank you in advance

Comment: When asking a database question, always define data types. Given your error, I guess `TimeId` is of type `Time`. The thing is you could take 1 or 100 days of right now, you'd still have the same time. I'm guessing you need to join `dateid` and get a date right? First extend your query to do that

Comment: Time has no concept of any date. So trying to compare  a time value to your manipulated value of getdate makes no sense, which is why the error is generated. Perhaps you intended to compare the current time (regardless of date) to the value stored in the database. That might cure the error but it seems you have more important design problems to solve.

Comment: [This fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a88f59471a10b6cafe78ac2b7297ca97) cures the error but you still need to address what the multi-date options of your GUI mean. No idea what "first minute" means as a filter option - does your expected user know?

Answer (score 0):

`GETDATE()` returns `datetime` but your column TimeId is actually time(3). You could use the following `CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)` but then you are just comparing the time and not the dates.

How do you get the corresponding date for `DateId`?